# In Mysql get rows that have a field that ends in space and one character

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to get all rows where the field given name ends in a space and a letter, any letter. Currently the SQL I have is

```
SELECT person_id FROM person_name 
  WHERE given_name LIKE '% M' 
    OR given_name LIKE '% C' 
    OR given_name LIKE '% A'
```

but instead of enumerating out all the letters I would like a query that is 
given_name like '% X' where X is any letter (upper and lower case).

I tried regexp **[a-zA-Z]** but couldn't figure out how to tell regexp that it was the last two characters in the string.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]$'
```

$ should match the end of the string.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want

```
SELECT * FROM `person_name` WHERE `given_name` REGEX " [a-zA-Z]$"
```

The `$` signals the end of the string.

Comment: So I did, thanks - but was that worth a downvote? The regex is correct, I believe

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT `given_name`
FROM table
WHERE `given_name` like '% _'
```